# How to run Microsoft Teams sample app in debug mode

Tags: debugging, microsoft-teams

I am using this app https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-personal-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore

It works fine.

I wish to extend the functionality - specifically in auth.js - so I need to be able to run it in Debug mode.

I have tried for some time but have no success getting a breakpoint hit. I use the instructions at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/debugging-microsoft-teams-app-locally-with-teams-toolkit as guidance but have no success. (In particular I don't have 'Debug (Chrome)' or same for Edge available as a config in VS Code.

Can anyone point to guidance on this please or perhaps advise if I need a specific launch.json config

Thanks

**Update** – the Teams sample code I was using comes from https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples

They run fine but I had no success getting them to debug. Any search for ‘Teams samples’ is going to find those first!

The repo linked from the ‘Samples’ button of the VS Code Teams Toolkit is at https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples and works as the article above describes.

As for why there are 2 sets of official samples, not cross referenced … go figure.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Why not just use browser debugging tools? It's not in Visual Studio, but rather directly in Chrome or Edge, but it's pretty reasonable to use

Comment: Please have a look at this doc-https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/debugging
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT thank you, I have this running now and have updated my question. Multiple sample code repos are clouding the issue I think.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question what exactly issue you are facing and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end?